# Can I say 'co-student'?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

I want to refer to a member of our lab, who is working with me on the same project, and I was wondering what would be the best term to use.

We are both mainly students, but we also work as Research Assistants.

I feel that **co-worker** might imply that we have a full-time jobs

I also feel that **lab member** might imply that we do separate/different things since the lab could have many students.

**co-student** seems perfect if this word existed - we're both students, but we also work together.

Comment: +1 for creativity, hell yes you can call them co-students, from now on I call other poeple in the bar my co-drinkers! You are my co-poster! I love it, I'll use this any chance I get, thank you for sharing!

Comment: co-labitator similar to co-habitator should work as well!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The more usual term in the UK would be *fellow student*. Academics who work together are *colleagues*.

Answer (score 8):

How about *lab partner*?  That would imply the two of you are working jointly.  *Research partner* might work, too.

Answer (score 7):

They are your *peers* not your co-students.

Answer (score 4):

When I was a student, we referred to students who shared our lab as *lab mates*, and those who shared classes as *classmates*.

Lab mates were specifically peers. Lab *members* could include anyone from techs to profs.

Answer (score 3):

- as to it already existing, the word 'co-student' does not show at all in [google books](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=co-student&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) and 'costudent' is [very rare](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=costudent&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3)
- it is not a terrible sounding neologism and would be understood with no problem, but there are other existing terms that are sufficient. In comparison to '[fellow student](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=costudent%2Cfellow+student&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3)' it is rare.

So it all depends on what you want to emphasize.

- If it is the education part, then **classmate** or **fellow student**
- if working, whether fulltime or not, then **colleague** or **co-worker**. In your particular instance, **lab member**, or **group** or **team member**, would also work.
- 'costudent' is not recommended, since it is not very common. A plain google search shows that it is used sometimes ([COCA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) shows nothing), but it looks like telescoped 'headlinese'.

Answer (score 2):

Collaborators?  (Co-lab-beraters?)  :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use, **Project Mate**,  to refer to a person who works with you on the same project.

Answer (score 0):

What about *fellow students*? What's wrong with that?

Answer (score -1):

Actually, the correct term is co-student.  Fellow student or class mate refers to the male gender.  Since college also enrolls females, it is more appropriate to use non-gender or androgynous reference terms.  Hope that answers you question.

Comment: You wrote, "Fellow student or class mate refers to the male gender". Actually, these terms are *not* gender-specific.